# ExpoAppAuth + Instagram Error: ExpoAppAuth.Get Auth: JSON deserialization error

Tags: json, react-native, expo, instagram, appauth

just trying to receive access token from instagram api. I am using expo app-auth and running on android. My usage is straight from demo https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-auth/#usage

Of course I changed config to:

```
let config = { 
issuer: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize',
scopes: ['user_profile', 'user_media'],
clientId: '33562202******'
};
```

And received that kind of error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: ExpoAppAuth.Get Auth: JSON deserialization error]
 - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:99:50 in fn
 - node_modules\@unimodules\react-native-adapter\build\NativeModulesProxy.js:15:41 in moduleName.methodInfo.name
 - ... 9 more stack frames from framework internals
```

Any tips how to manage with that kind of error? I guess that maybe instagram returns data in format different than JSON but have no green idea how to read that data, because of throwing error.